OpenCV Probabilistic and Standard Hough Line Transform giving very different results?
I'm new to CV, and I'm trying to detect an image in a computer screen. My approach is using Hough line transform to get possible edges that form the image. I was wondering why the standard cv2.HoughLines() doesn't work as well. Any insight helps. Thank you!
This is the original image:
Original Image
Probabilistic Hough Line Transform code:
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
                edges, # Input edge image
                1, # Distance resolution in pixels
                np.pi/180, # Angle resolution in radians
                threshold=300, # Min number of votes for valid line
                minLineLength=300, # Min allowed length of line
                maxLineGap=10 # Max allowed gap between line for joining them
                )

edges_color = cv2.cvtColor(edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

for points in lines:
    x1,y1,x2,y2=points[0]
    # Draw the lines joing the points
    # On the original image
    cv2.line(edges_color,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),3)

Probabilistic Hough Line Transform result:
Probabilistic Hough Transform Result
Standard Hough Line Transform code:
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(
                edges, # Input edge image
                1, # Distance resolution in pixels
                np.pi/180, # Angle resolution in radians
                threshold=300, # Min number of votes for valid line
                )
    
    edges_color = cv2.cvtColor(edges, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    for line in lines:
        for rho,theta in line:
            a=np.cos(theta)
            b=np.sin(theta)
            x0=a*rho
            y0=b*rho
            x1=int(x0+1000*(-b))
            y1=int(y0+1000*(a))
            x2=int(x0-1000*(-b))
            y2=int(y0-1000*(a))
            cv2.line(edges_color,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),2)

Standard Hough Line Transform result:
Standard Hough Line Transform Result

Please post the original image.

@toyotaSupra Just posted it - thanks!

But that is not an original image.

That's the image I'm running the algorithm from. Unfortunately, I am unable to upload the original image since it's sensitive information, sorry. Do you suggest that I do a different form of preprocessing? I'm using a Gaussian blur into a Canny filter into a small dilation.
I can also take a "similar" picture and upload it if that would be helpful.

I am looking at 300. You should reduce it. You can play around with values.

Reducing the threshold value creates an even messier image for the standard Hough transform. This is it with 200: https://imgur.com/a/ECUsCXE

When using cv2.HoughLines, you don't need to do this for rho,theta in line: Search  in Google for cv2.HoughLines
